# How to use keras predict_proba to output 2 columns of probability?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I use this code to predict the probability of 0 and 1 in `x_test`, but the result is only one column of probability. I really don’t know whether the probability of this column is the probability of 0 or the probability of 1.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

data_train = np.array([
[0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0],
[0, 2, 0],
[0, 3, 0],
[1, 0, 0],
[2, 0, 0],
[3, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 1],
[2, 1, 1],
[1, 2, 1],
[3, 1, 1],
])

data_test = np.array([
[1, 3],
[0, 4],
[5, 0]
])

x_train = data_train[:, :-1]
y_train = data_train[:, -1]
x_test = data_test

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', input_dim=2))
model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['binary_accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=1, verbose=1)
predict = model.predict_proba(x_test, batch_size=1)
print(predict)
```

And the result is only 1 column:

```
[[0.9431795]
 [0.47065434]
 [0.08615088]]
```

I want 2 columns of probability, the first column is the probability of 0, and the second column is the probability of 1, such as this:

```
 [[0.23334,0.76267]
    ……
 [0.84984,0.15685]
 [0.16663,0.83291]]
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to convert `y_train` to one-hot encoding by

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from keras.utils import np_utils

encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(y_train)
encoded_y = encoder.transform(y_train)
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_y)
```

running this code, `y_train` will become

```
array([[1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

Secondly, you need to change the output layer to

```
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

with these two modifications, you will get the desired output.

Comment: In this case (one-hot encoded labels and softmax output), they should also switch to `loss='categorical_crossentropy'` and `metrics='accuracy'`.