# Why use keras predict_proba to predict the probability has the same value?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

The data in my csv likes this:

```
[
[0, 0,……, 0],
[0, 1,……, 0],
[0, 2,……, 0],
[0, 3,……, 0],
[1, 0,……, 0],
[2, 0,……, 0],
[3, 0,……, 0],
[1, 1,……, 1],
[2, 1,……, 1],
[1, 2,……, 1],
[3, 1,……, 1],
]
```

The training set has 400,000 rows data and the test set has 200,000 rows data.

The value of `y_train` is only `0` and `1`, and there are more than 40 columns of data in csv.

I use this code to predict the probability of `1` with `x_test`,but all the probability in the result have the same value, why?

```
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from keras.utils import np_utils

train = pd.read_csv(r'train.csv')
test = pd.read_csv(r'test.csv')

x_train = train[:, :-1]
y_train = train[:, -1]

encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(y_train)
encoded_y = encoder.transform(y_train)
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_y)
x_test = test

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', input_dim=48))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['binary_accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=15, batch_size=50000, verbose=1)
predict = model.predict_proba(x_test, batch_size=50000)
print(predict[:,1]) #same value
```

output:

```
[[0.8432461],
[0.8432461],
[0.8432461],
[0.8432461],
[0.8432461],
[0.8432461],
……
[0.8432461]]
```

I don’t know whether the parameters of these lines of code are appropriate. From my data, there are only two categories 0 and 1. I need to predict the probability of the category whose label is 1.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', input_dim=48))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
```

Comment: Confused regarding your previous question? See updated answer (and my comment in the answer there).

Answer (score 0):

Binary cross-entropy loss should be used when your labels `y` are single digits, not one-hot encoded as you do here; from the [docs](https://keras.io/api/losses/probabilistic_losses/#binary_crossentropy-function):

> For each example, there should be a single floating-point value per prediction.

So you should remove the one-hot encoding:

```
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_y) # remove this line
```

change your last layer to

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
```

and use directly `encoded_y` as your labels in fitting:

```
model.fit(x_train, encoded_y, epochs=15, batch_size=50000, verbose=1)
```

In this setting, the single number you will get is the probability of class 1 (I just saw your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64583840/how-to-use-keras-predict-proba-to-output-2-columns-of-probability) on this).

Alternatively, you could keep the setting (labels and model) as is, but change to `loss='categorical_crossentropy'` (simply `metrics='accuracy'` will do the job).

Comment: I do it as you said,but all probability is 0.5.

Comment: Please look more closely to my answer. I did **not** say to use `Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')` with `loss='categorical_crossentropy'` (as you show in your now deleted answer); I said you could use `loss='categorical_crossentropy'` **alternatively** to the other changes, i.e. either/or.

Comment: @CR7 is everything OK now?

Comment: I don’t know what is wrong. My current prediction results are all 0.5. I need to change the training set and test set of other projects to try. If the results of other project is okay, I think there is something wrong in  my current project.

Comment: @CR7 Question (and hence the answer) was not about the data, since they are not available for us. What I have described is the correct settings & combinations of them regarding label format, activations, and loss function. We have no way of knowing your data, or if they are not appropriate for the task in hand, neither is that a *programming* question.